# Nuxt.js connection to Flask refused. Bad routing?

Tags: python, flask, frontend, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

I've tried to connect my Flask server to nuxt.js based on [this](https://www.codementor.io/@lautiamkok/creating-a-nuxt-application-with-python-frameworks-kd2yjqsfx) tutorial. I've created an environment variable env:

```
{
    HOST_URL: process.env.HOST_URL || 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'
  },
```

and connected it in my index file with axios

```
import axios from '~/node_modules/axios'
export default {
    async asyncData () {
      let {data} = await axios.get('/')
      console.log(data.data)
      return data.data
    },
```

When I tried to run the project which is described in the tutorial everything works fine.
When I do the same things to my own nubies code I got this error

[image]

the error disappears if I enter a direct link to the server like this axios.get('http://localhost:5000/').

It seems to me that somewhere in my code (which I initialized with webpack-simple) the routing changed to http://localhost:80
Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: If you haven't checked `process.env.HOST_URL`, do so :)

Comment: Just look into: process.env.HOST_URL.

Comment: @ATULKUMARSINGH, @A.J.Uppal Thank you! I've cheked it like this 
`console.log(process.env.HOST_URL)
        let {data} = await axios.get('/')` 
Here what I got: 

`http://127.0.0.1:5000                                                                                         14:45:31

 ERROR  connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80                                                                     14:45:33

  at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)`


Or there is another way to check it?

Comment: It looks like on that screen it's trying to connect to port 80, not port 5000.

Comment: @KenKinder, yes, it is and the main question is how to fix it:)